# Drinking wine in the winter

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Drinking wine in the winter
>
> Thinking deep in the brain
>
> If you want a do over
>
> Then you just add again.

What am I?

Comment: That's two really nice little riddles you've posted here so far! Keep 'em coming :-D

Comment: Really very good, but I can't bring myself to upvote due to the mis-spelling that you have to accept to solve it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> MULL

Explanation:

- *Drinking wine in the winter*

  > mulled wine is wine with sugar and spices added
- *Thinking deep in the brain*

  > *to mull* is to think about something for a considerable time
- *If you want a do over then you just add again.*

  > mull+again≈mulligan, defined [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mulligan) as *a free shot sometimes given [sic] a golfer in informal play when the previous shot was poorly played*

Comment: and i gave up after thinking to myself "mull again.... no, that does not seem right"

Comment: I typed "mullagain" into the online dictionary and it suggested proper spellings :) I don't play golf ...

Comment: [Mulligan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carey_Mulligan)? :-P